# High CPU load on ORMLite query

Tags: android, ormlite

We're experiencing a very high CPU load when executing the query below:

```
        //find user
    QueryBuilder<UserDTO, Long> userQb = userDao.queryBuilder();
    userQb.where().idEq(userId);
    UserDTO data = userQb.queryForFirst();

    //find events
    if (data != null) {
        QueryBuilder<EventViewDTO, Long> eventQb = eventDao.queryBuilder();
        data.eventViews = (ArrayList<EventViewDTO>) eventQb.join(userQb).query();
    }

    return data;
```

The resulting data is about 9kB in total. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The resulting data is about 9kB in total. Is there anything wrong with the code?

I don't immediately see any problems with your code.  I'd make sure that `userId` is in an index if you have a large table but I suspect that isn't the issue.

```
@DatabaseField(index = true)
private String userId;
```

You might also want to add an index to the foreign `UserDTO` field in the event table if that table is large but again I don't think the performance problem is on the Sqlite end unless your databases are large.

One query optimization that you could try is to use another `WHERE` constraint when getting the events instead of the join:

```
QueryBuilder<EventViewDTO, Long> eventQb = eventDao.queryBuilder();
// the "userDto" needs to be changed to whatever the foreign field name is
data.eventViews = eventQb.where().eq("userDto", data.id);
```

If you look at your logs, you might see a large number of GC activity which, I suspect, is the performance sink as well.  Although 9k is not too large it isn't small either from a DB perspective.  You might use the `QueryBuilder.selectColumns(...)` methods to see if it gets faster once you reduce the amount of data returned.  You may actually not need all of the columns.

You might want to also log the number of millis it is taking to do each query to make sure that it is the query that is causing the problem although you may already have done some profiling.